# how to apply proguard on both android project and service project at the same time

Tags: android, jar, proguard

I'm trying to use the proguard in my android application, I've wrote all my services in a separate project and package through maven as service jar. I'm using this service jar as dependency in my UI project.

I'm using maven android and proguard-maven-plugin to build/release my UI project. My question is how to apply Proguard for both project at same time, is it possible to do?

I tried running proguard separately on service project and add that jar to UI project but it's not worked.please guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't run proguard on jar file which are references by your android application (in your particular case, not in general).

Here is how android application is being compiled:

1. Compile all `.java` files into `.class`.
2. Unzip all jar files and extract `.class` files from them.
3. Apply proguard to all `.class` files (your application's `.class` files + all jars' .class files).
4. Convert `.class` files to `dex` format which results in `classes.dex` file

Basically, you shouldn't apply proguard on a jar file that is used by Android Application. If you have to apply proguard, then make sure all classes, interfaces, etc. that are used by your Android Application are not obfuscated by proguard.

I would recommend to just use Android's build system proguard step called `-obfuscate`. That would be the easiest way to go (and would make your life much easier when crash reports start coming in).

Comment: well,what i did was add my service jar as a -injars to my android app proguard.cfg file. and all the dependency in my service project  as a -libraryjars, when i run the proguard and run my app get crash, i think it because proguard has obfuscate all the libraryjars, is there any way i can stop external jars getting obfuscate when running proguard

Comment: You say you think its proguard, are you sure? What made you think so?

Comment: i'm new to this android and the proguard thing, i might wrong doing this,but one i used the following option i mange to get the app work    -keep public class org.springframework.http.**{ *;}
-keep public class org.codehaus.jackson.**{  *;}, if i doing please correct me inazruk...